# Me2pro synchronisation

Tags: magento

I have just started using ME2Pro to synchronise my Amazon orders with Magento.  The oreders arrive OK in Magento.  But I have just marked some as shipped and it is still showing on Amazon as unshipped.  How long should I wait for it to synchronise to tell Amazon it has been shipped?

Answer (score 0):

For synchronization, cron must be run for this extension.

So please whether check it is working or not.

When cron runs, it will automatically update in Amazon